# How to replicate WordPress categories with static HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm looking into converting my WordPress powered website into static HTML pages. I'll just edit pages in e.g. Responsive Site Designer, Dreamweaver or SublimeText.

The only issue I have is how would I sort stuff in categories like I did in WordPress? I could make a load of folders and sub folders but that is just plain madness. Would love to know your thoughts on this.

Guess the same approach with categories could be also applied with tags.

If possible I would like to skip using PHP.

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about the URL structure of WordPress categories (e.g. `www.website.com/category1/category2/post-title`), then yes you'll need to make your categories into directories.

If you're talking about assigning categories to a given post/page, you can do this with PHP variables. When making your post, give it the variable that describe its categories. Then you can call the posts where they are relevant to the category.

Then you can make a template such as "post-brief.php" that takes a snippet of the article an the title. Then you can make a category page that says get the post-brief.php of all variables in x category.

Comment: How are you going to use PHP variables in static files?

Comment: Preferable not but if there is no other way. Was thinking of .htaccess rewrite file but don't think I can do it at all without php.